# Show Flash object in Selenium/PhantomJS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, flash, phantomjs

I'm developing a series of webcrawlers and one of the websites that I have to navigate uses a Flash-generated captcha. Only the captcha code uses Flash, the rest is regular HTML. I wanted to know how can Selenium/PhantomJS show this Flash object so that I can take a screenshot with it and send the file to our captcha-solving service. Any tips? I'm programming in C#, Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS by Ryan Bridges](http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/) (with flash support) or [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/) (works on top of [FireFox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)).

SlimerJS has the same API as PhantomJS, you need to use [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (X Virtual Frame Buffer) for work with them.

Comment: Thanks, mate, I'll take a look into these alternatives